# On defining a macro using \edef and assigning the x-component of a given node to it

Tags: tikz-node, tikz-calc

Let us assume that we have a node in Tikz and we want to have a macro called \myx using \edef to assign the x-component of the node to \myx.
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,4);
\node  at (1,1) (A){$A$};
\node  at (2,3) (B){$B$};
\node  at ($(A)+(B)$) (C){$C$};
\fill[red] let \p1 = (C),
in
(\x1,\y1) circle [radius=0pt]
;
\edef \myx{\x1}
\node at (0,0) {\myx};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know the variable \x1 is not known out of the \fill. But how we can assign \x1 to \myx using the \edef?

Comment: Have you tried using \tikzmath instead of \edef ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `math` tikz library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{math}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,4);
        \node  at (1,1) (A){$A$};
        \node  at (2,3) (B){$B$};
        \node  at ($(A)+(B)$) (C){$C$};
        \fill[red] (C) circle [radius=0pt] ;

       \tikzmath{
          coordinate \c;
          \c=(C);
          \x1=\cx;
       }

      \edef \myx{\x1}
      \node at (0,0) {\myx}; % or \node at(0,0) {\x1};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hafid